# Why is this execlp() function not executing?

Tags: c, exec

I'm trying to fork a number of child processes, then use execlp() on each child to execute another set of code. execlp() does not seem to be executing.

I've tried execl() and execlp(), but don't know what I have written incorrectly.

```
 // create child procs that use execlp()
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0){
            perror("fork");
            abort();
        } else if (pids[i] == 0){
            // do child work here
            execlp("./fileWriter", "./fileWriter", num_threads, NULL);
            printf("got here in child proc\n");
            exit(0);
        }
}
```

I'm expecting it to execute a separate file, which right now I've just written a print statement in so I know when that other file actually runs. Rather than that, I'm getting "got here in child proc", which I added so I knew when the child processes skipped over the execlp() command.

Comment: What's the return code from `execlp`? Presumably `-1`. What is `errno` set to?

Comment: What is `num_threads`?  Please show a [mcve].

Comment: To be pedantic, `NULL` should be cast to `(char *)`.

Comment: @nate num_threads is an integer that will be passed to the fileWriter telling it how many threads to create when it runs its piece of code.

Comment: Okay, but the arguments you pass to `execlp` have to be strings.

Comment: @nate yes, it is a string, my bad. It's changed from an int to a string to be passed in.

Comment: If you had posted a [mcve], we would not have needed to have that discussion...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are mostly there but I'll give you the version I have running:

```
char cNum[20];
// create child procs that use execlp()
for (ii = 0; ii < num; ii++)
{
    sprintf(cNum,"%d", num_threads);
    if ((pids[ii] = fork()) < 0){
        perror("fork");
        abort();
    } else if (pids[ii] == 0){
        // do child work here
        ret=execlp("./fileWriter", "./fileWriter", cNum, (char *) NULL);
        printf("got here in child proc: %d\n",ret);
        perror("execlp");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

The execlp has to be a string (you got that part) and it is "helpful" if you examine the error returns to see where errors are coming from.